# guardar datos en el dispositivo móvil

Tags: genexus, programación-móvil

Estoy tratando de guardar un archivo txt o guardar datos en el dispositivo, pero el archivo siempre devuelve la ruta de la carpeta de Windows. (aplicación online).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando genexus 17U5

Comment: [No fuerces una etiqueta](/help/tagging) en los títulos ([es.so] no es un foro). Además, muestra el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente el procedimiento esté generado Online y esta ejecutando en el servidor.

Pará ejecutar localmente debes ponerle la propiedad [Connectivity Support](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20911,Connectivity%20Support%20property) en Offline.

Para guardar datos pequeños en el dispositivo, ver también la [API de Client Storage](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31272,ClientStorage%20external%20object).

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de escribir una pequeña tabla, o una cadena de 200 caracteres más, o una pequeña colección en la aplicación online?